# EF Code First DBContext and Transactions

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I would like know what is the best possible way to implement transactions with `DBContext`. In particular,

1. Does `DbContext.SaveChanges` implement transaction internall if i change multiple entities?
2. If i want to call `DbContext.SaveChanges` multiple times(same contxet/different contxets), how transaction can be achieved?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1. Yes. `SaveChanges` uses transaction internally.
2. Use `TransactionScope` to wrap multiple calls to `SaveChanges`

Example:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    // Do something 
    context.SaveChanges();
    // Do something else
    context.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Be sure to be using Sql 2008 or later as the database (or have the MSDTC service running on the client). Previous versions will escalate the transaction to a distributed transaction on the second `SaveChanges`. This is due to how `DbContext` internally handles the opening and closing of its connection.

Comment: Is is possible to get an identity from the first save changes?  I always see Id = 0.

Comment: @JarrettV - I think your issue is because of the IsolationLevel settings. Lowering it might help...

Comment: This wont work with EF 4.3.1. We will have to open the connection on the Objectcontext explicitly before we call context.SaveChanges().

Comment: @renegadeMind: Of course this will work with DbContext. What you describe is advanced way used when you want to avoid distributed transaction.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes you are correct; but don't we want to avoid DTC by default? I assumed that we do and hence my answer!

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous operation do the following.

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    // Do something 
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    // Do something else
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

References: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions)