# Should I use TransactionScope with DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

According to this link: [EF Code First DBContext and Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028626/ef-code-first-dbcontext-and-transactions)

I should wrap the savechanges in a TransactionScope using statement.

I thought the SaveChanges works like or is a transactional method.

Example:

In a service method I am deleting and adding different entities in one http request at the end of the service method I do a SaveChanges one ONE Context.

I will have never multiple context. Its always the same context inject by Ninject created for the lifetime of a http request and shared among the repositories.

So is it true that I only need to wrap tehe DbContext.SAveChanges in a TransactionScope when I have multiple dbcontext ? - because these could be multiple databases aka a distributed transaction - ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to wrap your SaveChanges call in another TransactionScope if;

1. If you are not trying to use multiple context in the same transaction.
2. If you are not making multiple SaveChanges calls even with the same context. For instance, one SaveChanges after Delete, another SaveChanges after add...

In summary, you can do multiple delete/add operations with the same context, and call the SaveChanges method once in the end - they will all be applied in one transaction. TransactionScope is only necessary if you have nested transaction scenarios.

Comment: Ok so far I have understood it right then, BUT what scenario could I have to make multiple SaveChanges after Delete and another after Add..? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: A sample scenario may be like this:  
Suppose that you got two business methods (AddX and UpdateY) that include custom business logic like validation of objects or some calculations and each can be consumed separately. Since they can be used for independent business scenarios they call SaveChanges to end their operations.  
Now suppose you're adding another business method (UpdateZ) which needs to add X and update Y to complete. Since updateZ reuses addX and updateY business methods, it needs to wrap those calls inside another TransactionScope to manage those two operations in one transaction.

Comment: SaveChanges() push data to the server. Depending on the type of data and your and other users  isolation level, using both SaveChanges() and TransactionScope will have effect on locks and accessibility for others on this Db during the transaction lifetime. Eg. you can start by locking a row to avoid conflicts on the final save.