# Does Entity framwork save command commits the transaction?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using a transaction and want to learn to commit inner commit?

```
        await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

        try
        {
            // update table 1

            // update table 2

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // necessary to use this???
            await transaction.CommitAsync();   // necessary to use this???

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();

            throw;
        }
```

Should I use commit transaction after `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`. My entity framework version is core 3.0.

Comment: If the same dbcontext is the only participant to a transaction then you don't t need a transaction at all. SaveChanges will wrap all the resulting statements in a transaction.

Comment: table 1 and table 2 is in same db context, so should not I use transaction?

Comment: Yes, no need to wrap in a transaction as long as you only call `SaveChanges` once, and as long as you are using the same DbContext instance.
Your updates to table1 and table2 only 'occur' during the SaveChanges.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028691/

Comment: Little late, but in this case: Could .SaveChangesAsync be omitted and the updates would still be saved on commit?